# Block a specific url request

Tags: urls, request-filter

I probably have a plugin that makes a request to an URL slowly down my website. At the moment I'm still debugging the issue but, in the meantime, is there a way to prevent Wordpress to request this URL?

I know there's the rule define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true); but it actually blocks every request.

Comment: "probably have a plugin"?  Use chrome's Network tab to find out what is going on.  If a plugin is noticeably slowing down your site it should be removed.

Comment: you can't check which plugin is requesting that url with network tab

Comment: No it won't tell you the plugin but I would think it should give you some hints

Comment: The fact this URL request an external POST to its domain and, in the meantime, I figured out the problem, I need to block the requests to this URL

Comment: Try this plugin, it lists all the http requests with option to block it's main url & the file by which the request was triggered, it also has some hooks in order to reduce it's dataset and is very thoughtful (although i need a more nuanced solution..i came across this question and the plugin below..so hopefully this is what u anyone needs) https://wordpress.org/plugins/snitch/

Answer (score 1):

Like you suggested, use `WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL` to stop all external URL requests.  And then use `WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS` to set allowed URLs.

From the WP Codex, found on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php).

***wp-config.php***

```
define( 'WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true );
define( 'WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS', 'api.wordpress.org,*.github.com' );
```

> Block external URL requests by defining WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL as true and this will only allow localhost and your blog to make requests. The constant WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS will allow additional hosts to go through for requests. The format of the WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS constant is a comma separated list of hostnames to allow, wildcard domains are supported, eg *.wordpress.org will allow for all subdomains of wordpress.org to be contacted.

Note: This could have unintended consequences like potentially breaking plugins, auto updates, etc.

Comment: yes but I have to block only one. All the other hosts are allowed. I'm also using Google AdSense so, blocking every request isn't practical for me because of AdSense that loads very different URLs every time